# AngularJS : Clear $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I have a watch function in my AngularJS application.

```
$scope.$watch('quartzCrystal', function () {
   ...
}
```

However, after some condition (in my example, changing the page at my [single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)) I want to stop that watch (as like clearing timeout).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 531, accepted):

`$watch` returns a deregistration function. Calling it would deregister the `$watcher`.

```
var listener = $scope.$watch("quartz", function () {});
// ...
listener(); // Would clear the watch
```

Comment: Do you know if it's a good practice to deregister all your listeners at the end of a controller lifecycle (like on a `$on('$destroy')`) or AngularJS will take care of them? thanks!

Comment: All watchers will be removed when the scope is destroyed, you don't need to manage those

Comment: @UmurKontacı - do you have a source for your claim that when a scope is destroyed the watchers are removed? It does not appear to be part of the [`$destroy` function](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/cceb455fb167571e26341ded6b595dafd4d92bc6/src/ng/rootScope.js#L693)

Comment: You can see an interesting discussion here that explains the matter:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4574
Basically, if you assign a listener to the $rootScope, you have to unassign it your self, or it will persist through $scope changes. Watchers on $scope get destroyed with the $scope ($scopes are not singletons in Angular, and they get created and destroyed when needed).

Comment: But, what if i only want the watcher for checking if the value exists and then when it exists do some changes and then de register itself i already tried - 
var listen = $scope.$watch('mvIdentity.currentUser', function(currentUser) { 
test = 1;
console.log("--> " + $scope.updateemail + " -- " + test);
listen(); });

Comment: @UmurKontacı Actually deadman's comment is perfectly valid as your original comment is not correct for every case.

Comment: Note: $scope.$$watchers contains all the watches on a particular scope. It is dangerous but you can manipulate them. Courtesy: https://coderwall.com/p/d_aisq

Comment: Note: `$scope.$$watchersCount` helps a lot for debugging.

Answer (score 49):

scope.$watch returns a function that you can call and that will unregister the watch.

Something like:

```
var unbindWatch = $scope.$watch("myvariable", function() {
    //...
});

setTimeout(function() {
    unbindWatch();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Yes, you're able to unbind within the watchFn! Simple use-case: you want to watch and execute the watchFn only once, then stop watching.

Comment: Am I able to rebind the watch after I call the unbind function, like calling it again?

Comment: This was useful. Doing the unbindWatch in a timeout seems important in my testing.

Comment: In this case you should use $timeout, which you can also de-register!

Comment: Best to avoid timeouts

Answer (score 26):

You can also clear the watch inside the callback if you want to clear it right after something happens. That way your $watch will stay active until used.

Like so...

```
var clearWatch = $scope.$watch('quartzCrystal', function( crystal ){
  if( isQuartz( crystal )){
    // do something special and then stop watching!
    clearWatch();
  }else{
    // maybe do something special but keep watching!
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Some time your $watch is calling `dynamically` and it will create its instances so you have to call deregistration function before your `$watch` function

```
if(myWatchFun)
  myWatchFun(); // it will destroy your previous $watch if any exist
myWatchFun = $scope.$watch("abc", function () {});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have too much watchers and you need to clear all of them, you can push them into an array and destroy every `$watch` in a loop.

```
var watchers = [];
watchers.push( $scope.$watch('watch-xxx', function(newVal){
   //do something
}));    

for(var i = 0; i < watchers.length; ++i){
    if(typeof watchers[i] === 'function'){
        watchers[i]();
    }
}

watchers = [];
```

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, every custom watch should be removed when you leave the scope.

It helps in better memory management and better app performance.

```
// call to $watch will return a de-register function
var listener = $scope.$watch(someVariableToWatch, function(....));

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    listener(); // call the de-register function on scope destroy
});
```