# Is there a good way to 'Freeze' Angular scopes and children that are not being used

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on a project that basically consists of complicated form containers repeated in an ng-repeat. Each of these forms has enough functionality that it could easily be its own angular app, but instead they are repeated on the screen, and there can be up to 30 of them.

With 5 or more of these on the screen, performance becomes very slow. Although I tried to disbale some of our heavier features, it seems that the big performance wins just come from disabling the 'uninteractable' scopes.

I am looking for a good pattern to 'freeze' the unused scopes. I want them to maintain their state, but I don't want them to listen or be attached to anything until the user focuses on the form that they apply to.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code my first thought is to use a directive to control that.

You could use the bind to the forms, and or use $watch(using $watch would depend on your setup) so that you have finer control over the scope.

here are some links:

[for directives in general](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

[for $watch and other ways of controlling the scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)

Answer (score 0):

Are all the forms in the view port at the same time? If not, you could add / remove forms to the DOM (using ng-include f.e.) based on whether they are visible to the user. This way watches are removed and added again when needed.

Otherwise, if you have a lot of watches you specify in your form controller, you can [unwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957614/angular-js-clear-watch) when not focused and rewatch when getting back the focus. This won't reduce the number of watches created by the (native) directives inside your form. This number can perhaps be reduced by using [bind-once](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce).