# Angular directive and http, model not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When `$scope.instrumentNames` is setting inside the controller like on the code provided **it works**

When `$scope.instrumentNames` is setting in the HTTP `success` function it **doesn't work**

The data returned by the `http` function IS an Array.

```
Console.log(data)//["Guitar", "Bass", "Violin"]
Console.log($scope.instrumentNames) //["Guitar", "Bass", "Violin"]
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller("PrivateProfileController",
    ["$scope", "$http", "$routeParams",  function( $scope, $http, $routeParams ) {

        $scope.instrumentNames = ["Guitar", "Bass", "Violin"];//WORKING !

        function loadInstrumentNames(){
            $http({
                url: '/Instrument/getInstrumentsName',
                method: "GET"
            }).success(function(data){
                //data = ["Guitar", "Bass", "Violin"]
                $scope.instrumentNames = data;//NOT WORKING 
            });
        }

        loadInstrumentNames()
    }]
);
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('autoComplete', [function($timeout) {
    return    {
        restrict: "A",
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.autocomplete({
                source: scope[attrs.uiItems],
                select: function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                      element.trigger('input');
                    }, 200);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

**Template**

```
<input auto-complete ui-items="instrumentNames">
```

It's like the directive is called before the `http success` is finished. Im stuck with this problem and any help or suggestion would be very appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: your success callback says `instrumentCodes`

Comment: Its a typo.. the problem is the same, the code provided here is not a copy/paste

Comment: the issue is likely the directive reading from the scope _before_ your request has completed.  Your directive needs to be binding to the parent scope and checking for changes on that.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's like the directive is called before the http success is finished.

I'm sure this is exactly what is happening. After the request to `/Instrument/getInstrumentsName` has been made, and before the response, the directive code will run. When the link function runs, `scope[attrs.uiItems]` will be `undefined`. You need to wait until the data comes back before doing the `autocomplete` call.

This can be done with a `$watch`. Something like this:

```
app.directive('autoComplete', [function($timeout) {
    return    {
        restrict: "A",
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.uiItems, function(uiItems) {
                if (uiItems) {
                    element.autocomplete({
                        source: scope[attrs.uiItems],
                        select: function() {
                            $timeout(function() {
                              element.trigger('input');
                            }, 200);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

You probably only want that to run once, so you can set a var equal to that $watch call, which returns a deregistering function. Call that function at the end, and it won't run the `$watch` anymore.

```
var unwatch = scope.$watch(attrs.uiItems, function(uiItems) {
   if (uiItems) {
       //everything you want to do with the data
       unwatch();
   }
});
```

Comment: Perfect it is working! thanks ! Just don't totally understand what your saying about calling the function at the end. Could you provide some code ?? Is it something like var checked = false; if (uiItems && !checked){checked = true; //...}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957614/angular-js-clear-watch - see the answer to this question. If you use var listener = $scope.$watch etc then if you call that function via listener() it will automatically deregister the $watch.

Comment: Added some code. See the question posted in the comment above too.