# Bind expressions once in Angular 1.0.X?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch, angularjs-filter

I'm running into some performance issues because one of my views can potentially have tons of expressions being bound and as a result tons watches firing for each.

Is there a way to output an expression once and then not watch it for changes?

I'm thinking like a filter or something along these lines:

```
{{ something.mytext | nowatch }}
```

But I'm open to anything!

I found [this tutorial](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html) that describes what I'm looking for in Angular 1.3, unfortunately as of now I am stuck in an old version (1.0.7).

Comment: I think you can use [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce), but not sure whether it supports 1.0.x.

Comment: You could also potentially clear the `$watch`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957614/angular-js-clear-watch

Comment: Awesome I'll check out bindonce. As for potentially clearing the watch @DavinTyron - do you know if one would be able to access the specific watch pertaining to a given variable in a filter applied to it?