# Do I need to manually undo any watches in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When a directive is instantiated, a watch is configured.

```
scope.$watch('propertyName', function(value) {});
```

Do I have do do anything to prevent a memory leak when the directive is destroyed?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14957688/1260204

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No -- angular will take care of cleaning up watches when the associated `scope` gets destroyed.

If you want to clear a watch however; the $watch function returns a function, which will de-register the watch when called.

```
var unregister = $scope.$watch('myVar', function() { /* ... */ });
unregister();
```